# How to display JSON data that is stored in txt file to Datatable?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have a JSON file stored in .txt file and I'd like to display it into my datatable. Following [this tutorial](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html), I have set up the "ajax" path on my JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt"
    } );
} );
```

However, if I set up "columns" in the JS, the modal to display the datatable doesn't showed up and all the jQuery events failed.

```
"columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
```

is there anything I missed?

Comment: did you try debugging in console with console.log()?

Comment: @M.Hermant yep, I got this error `TypeError: column is undefined`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have right structure json

follow this json file: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/objects.txt

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "position": "Accountant",
        "salary": "$170,750",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office": "Tokyo",
        "extn": "8422"
    }]
}
```

because can't access txt file，I give you this example show how is right, hope helpful for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/objects.txt
    var data =[{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Garrett Winters",
            "position": "Accountant",
            "salary": "$170,750",
            "start_date": "2011/07/25",
            "office": "Tokyo",
            "extn": "8422"
        }];
    $('#example').DataTable({
        //"ajax": "https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "data": data,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "name"
        },
        {
            "data": "position"
        },
        {
            "data": "office"
        },
        {
            "data": "extn"
        },
        {
            "data": "start_date"
        },
        {
            "data": "salary"
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the correct format of JSON. But the debugger remain shows error `column is undefined`, in fact I copied paste your code and it remain shows the same error.

Comment: That's weird! This example can work, shouldn't have the error, are you sure you use the same code? Or add your complete code and console window.

Comment: Sure I use the same code. Moreover, I copied your JSON. I have another datatable loaded in `<iframe>` on the same page and working flawlessly. But I don't know what's wrong with this one.
Is there any issue for loading another datatable using iframe?

Comment: yes, you can load another datatable use iframe. Check your code again, maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing

```
"ajax": "data/objects.txt"
```

to

```
"ajax": "/data/objects.txt"
```

Note the leading `/`.  Your URL is a relative URL, so the system will use the full URL then add `data/objects.txt`.  For example

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/some/path/data/objects.txt
```

Using the leading `/` makes it a root-relative URL so it will always path to:

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/data/objects.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.
But I think the problem is not that, because if I didn't add "columns" in my JS then the modal would show up and datatable is shown inside. However, it says error `Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.` and rows number is correct.